# XMLReader returning "\n " instead of value

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm having a strange issue and I can't really find the cause. It just suddenly stopped working and I don't know what triggered it.

I'm using `XMLReader` in C# to read an xml file. I'm reading the values from the xml file like this:

```cs
if(subReader2.MoveToAttribute("X"))
    float.TryParse(reader.Value, NumberStyles.Any
           , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out pt.point.X);
```

The xml contains a tag like this:

```xml
<Point X="0" Y="0" Easing="Linear" EaseIn="True" EaseOut="True" />
```

When it reads the attributes `X` and `Y`, `reader.Value` returns `\n` for some reason. It has worked before, but something is stopping it now. The attributes, *Easing*, *EaseIn* and *EaseOut* are being read just fine. So I have no idea why `X` and `Y` would fail.

[The full xml file](http://pastebin.com/PHNXF1zh)

[The complete parsing function](http://pastebin.com/tnzGWHxd)

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try setting the XmlReader.Settings.IgnoreWhiteSpace setting to 'true' [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx)

Comment: What is the datatype of pt.point?  Could you add that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have `read.Value`, shouldn't that be `subReader2.Value`?

Comment: Ah yes.. I guess thats what you get for staring yourself blind on your code.. Thanks for the help and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are pointing `subReader2` at the X attribute and then taking a value from `reader`. Is there a reason you're using a separate reader for each loop?

Comment: _I suck at the XMLReader_ /hide
Thanks for the answer tho ^^ Had been staring too long at the code.

Comment: If you suck at it, then why are you using it?